# Bypass .Net v3.5 verification when installing SQL Server 2008 Express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, installation

For some reason, when I try to install `SQL Server 2008 Express`, I get an error saying that I need to have `.Net Framework 3.5` installed first, but the thing is: I already have! So could anybody tell me if I can bypass this verification by updating a registry key or something? I have np with visual studio or any other thing... just when I try to install sql express.

Comment: Are both SQL and the .NET in the same language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this once before. Make sure that it is installed. Reinstall if necessary. I believe what I did was install SP1. SQL Server 2008 has a tendency of trying to install the Compact Framework 3.5 and based on the build or refresh of SQL, Compact Framework 3.5 SP1. HTH!

Answer (score 1):

Installing Windows Installer 4.5 worked for me. Once installed, the message goes away.

Comment: However, it didn't install on Windows 7